# crystal report details sections together

Tags: crystal-reports

after hours of unsuccessful solving this problem, I need help...

I have a report with two subreports....Both of subreports contains only one page, and diplays the employment information... when I print main report only for one employment, it is all ok, first page is first subreport, second page is second subreport...

But,

when i try to print a main report for two or more employers, then I first get only first pages (first subreport) for all employers and then after that second pages (second subreport)... of course, this is not OK, because, i should get second subreport after first subreport for each employer, not after all first subreport for all employers is printed...

Now, I get
page1
page1
page1.....
page2
page2...

therefore, i Need this:
page1
page2
page1
page2
...

Here is a picture of main report

[image: image of main report]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do to solve your problem is making a group by employee ID and place those subreports inside that group and link them by employee ID with main report.

Comment: I try this, and it is the same... I found a solution for this... just change subreports links and that will solve this problem

Comment: of course after making the group by employee ID you will have to link those subreports by employee ID with main report

Comment: @user1562652 you will get there eventually with Crystal reports.